# Accessing data in specific line in section

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access generated form with a section that contain a lot of lines (different records) I'm trying to get the data in a specific label in specific line in VBA.

I am familiar with VB, but I couldn't manage to get that data (in edit mode of the form this label is single and don't contain all the lines)

I tried to look in the net, but couldn't find anything relevant.

I hope i was clear enough with my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're saying that you want to read what's in a specific field in one particular record. Yuu said label, but the label will be the same for all records. If you want the value of a field in specific record, you need to be in that record, then pull the value by using something like "strMyVariable = Forms!myformname!myfieldname". This will set the value of strMyVariable to that form field's value at the current time. I hope this sheds some light on the process, but if I misunderstood the question, please elaborate and I'll try to help.